# Do defaults need to be supplied for Firebase RemoteConfig?

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-remote-config

Supplying defaults is one of the steps when using RemoteConfig. It usually looks something like this:

```
let sefaults: [String: NSObject] = [
        "key1" : "value1" as NSObject,
        "key2" : "value2" as NSObject
    ]
FIRRemoteConfig.remoteConfig().setDefaults(defaults)
```

I've found RemoteConfig works perfectly fine without the above. Is the above necessary? Also, what is it doing? Seems to be a no-op.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No it is not necessary to provide defaults. **However**, if you don't your app will use the static default of the type you have defined (the static default value of a string, a boolean etc)

The way in which Firebase Remote Config decides on a value can be described as follows:

- First it checks if there is a **cached value** that was stored from the server, if there is it uses that.
- If there is **no cached value**, it looks to the **defaults** defined either programmatically or in the defaults file. (When you call `setDefaults()`)
- If there is **no value cached from the server**, and **no value in defaults**, it uses the system default for that type. 
  So even though it might not look like it is used to you, you should test your app with a clean installation and no internet to determine if its working as expected.

More info can be found here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/
[image: Firebase Remote Config Default Values Decision Making]

Comment: No, it will always use the server fetched values as first priority. If it can't reach the server for some reason (ie lack of internet or you accessing the values before the server has responded) then it will use the default value from setDefaults(). The device isn't notified when there is a new value, it will only get the new value after the cache time (which is default 12 hours after the last successful fetch).  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig#fetch()

Comment: Hi @riggaroo, post https://riggaroo.co.za/custom-file-template-group-android-studiointellij/ is extremely useful/helpful. I found 1 small bug tho, causing the entire IDE to lock up (using AS2.3); requiring a `forced quit` on Mac. In case you're still maintaining the post so that others don't run into the same _locked up IDE_, in `MvpViewActivity.java.ftl` on line 6 there is `${classname}Contract ..`  The token variable there is not camel-cased like all the other occurrences - should be `${className}`. With that update, the solution worked like a charm. Big thanks for sharing your notes there